# How to Pull XCOM value in PostgresOperator

Tags: python, airflow

Here I am pushing XCOM value:

```
task_get_username_bash = BashOperator(
                task_id='execute_bash',
                bash_command='whoami',
                xcom_push=True)
```

So in XCOMs it stores like {'return_value' : '$USER'} (in my case $USER = 'airflow').

Then I want to pull this *return_value* from XCOM:

```
task_insert_new_row = PostgresOperator(
                task_id='insert_new_row',
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
                sql='''INSERT INTO table_name VALUES
                (%s, %s, %s);''',
                parameters=(uuid.uuid4().int % 123456789,
                            "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='execute_bash', key='return_value') }}",
                            datetime.now()))
```

But PostgresOperator interpret Macros reference as str. How to pull XCOM in PostgresOperator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
task_insert_new_row = PostgresOperator(
                task_id='insert_new_row',
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
                sql='''INSERT INTO table_name VALUES
                (%s, '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='execute_bash', key='return_value') }}', %s);''',
                parameters=(uuid.uuid4().int % 123456789, datetime.now()))
```

Comment: What if I have a `sql=file.sql` parameter and I can't modify it, I can only pass some parameters that came from variables inside DAG, and one of them have the `ti.xcom_pull(...)` content?

Comment: @Vladyslav do you know how to push return value by postgres to other operator. Imagine instead of bash script, you have sql operator. If you know please help me with that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614989/how-to-pass-the-result-from-first-query-to-the-second-one-with-postgresoperator